# Python ImportError after CMake install

Tags: python, c++, cmake, boost-python

I am starting with CMake and I encountered the following problem when using Boost Python. A sample 'hello world' programs requires boost and python libraries. Before running cmake I create 'build' directory and this is where I ran cmake. I am able to generate a shared library and use it from that directory (with python), but when I type make install and my library is placed in source directory python is not able to read it throwing an error:

> *ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

project( test )
enable_language(CXX)

set( LIB_NAME pylib )

# ---------------------------
# Find Boost Python library
# ---------------------------
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

if( Boost_FOUND )
   message( STATUS "-> Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
   message( STATUS "-> Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: " ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
   message( STATUS "-> Boost_LIBRARIES: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

# ---------------------------
# Find Python library
# ---------------------------
find_package( PythonLibs REQUIRED )
if( PythonLibs_FOUND )
   message( STATUS "-> PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
   message( STATUS "-> PYTHON_LIBRARY_DIRS: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
   message( STATUS "-> PYTHON_LIBRARIES: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )

   include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

set( SRC hello.cpp )

add_library( ${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${SRC} )

target_link_libraries( ${LIB_NAME} 
   ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_LIBRARIES} 
)

set_target_properties( ${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON )
set_target_properties( ${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX .so )
set_target_properties( ${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "" )

install( TARGETS ${LIB_NAME} 
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Comment: You got the error because `libboost_python.so.1.64.0` is not in a directory searched by the dynamic loader (`ld`). See more about such libraries and a way CMake may affect on them here: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for answer. Why does it work then when I run it inside 'build' directory? Also, it works when I copy manually (cp in linux) the pylib.so file somewhere else.

Comment: `Why does it work then when I run it inside 'build' directory?` - The article explains, that in the build directory references to other libraries are **absolute paths**. But when libraries are installed, references becomes just **filenames**. As for the second question, it depends where you have copied the library `pylib.so`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I copied the library from 'build' directory one up where the CMakeLists.txt is (this is where the install command puts the library).